# Prove that $ a^6 = b^{11} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $a, b \in G$, where $G$ is a group, and $|a| = 12$ and $|b|=22$.  If $\langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle \neq \{e\}$, prove that $a^6  = b^{11}$.

Comment: Anything you tried?

Comment: I'm stuck.  It may help to identify an element in the intersection that is not e and find the order of that element?  Need more guidance.  I feel like this is a problem where if you know the "trick", it is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

The order of $\langle a\rangle \cap \langle b\rangle$ has to divide both $12$ and $22$. If this subgroup is not trivial, then it must have order $2$-which elements of $\langle a\rangle$ and $\langle b\rangle$ have order $2$?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the order of $\langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle$ divides both $|a|$ and $|b|$ because it's a subgroup of both $\langle a \rangle$ and $\langle b \rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $x\in\langle a\rangle$ and $y\in\langle b\rangle$ with $x=y$ then $x$ and $y$ must have equal order.